# ‘Could not open SDE workspace’ Error when running Multithreaded Calls on a geoprocessing service

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service

I have a python based geoprocessing service running on arcgis server 10.8 which is deployed on several environments. There is an application that makes multithreaded calls (roughly 9 calls concurrently) but about 2 or 3 will fail every time. I get one of the following 4 errors:

1. Error executing tool. {Name of Tool}  : Could not open SDE workspace. or RuntimeError: Object: Could not open SDE workspace {Path to sde}/testgis.sde
2. Connection information provided was for a non-administrative user
3. RuntimeError: cannot open {Path to sde}\GIS.sde\GIS.DBO.TravelPolygons\GIS.DBO.TP_SITES_60'
4. Error executing tool. {Name of Tool}: ERROR 000229: Cannot open {Path to sde}\GIS.sde\GIS.DBO.Designation_PC
   Usually the service will fail at the first time the script tries to connect/query a database table sometimes at the second or third time it tries to connect (bullet 3 or 4). I do not get any error if a single call is made and it is only happening in our production environment. The concurrent calls work in our lower environments.  My theory so far is that the concurrent calls may be causing locks which prevents a few of the threads from connecting to the database. Adding a delay is not an option on the application side. I have tried to adding a random delay right before it connects using the sde in the geoprocessing service code but it has not worked consistently. Does anyone know a way to get around the locks or any database settings that could be changed?

Here are the two functions where the errors typically occur:

```
    def getCTfromTable (x,y,minutes):

    tableName = g_CT_Table_Name
    isFound = False
    Cts=''
    expression = 'lat ='+str(y) +' and  long='+str(x) +' and traveltime = '+str(minutes)
    arcpy.AddMessage("where clause CT " + expression)


    g_CT_Full_Path = os.path.join(g_SDE_Location,g_CT_Table_Name)
    arcpy.AddMessage (g_CT_Full_Path)
    
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(g_CT_Full_Path, ['OBJECTID','lat','long', 'cts'], expression) as cursor:
            isFound = True
            for row in cursor:
                Cts = row

    return Cts

def getTPfromtable(x,y,minutes):
    tp = None
    tableName = "TP_sites_"+minutes
    expression ='latitude ='+str(y) +' and longitude='+str(x)

    isFound = False
    arcpy.AddMessage("where clause TP " + expression)

    g_TP_Table_1 =  g_TP_Table+str(int(minutes))
    layerpPath = os.path.join(g_SDE_Location,g_TP_Table_1)
    arcpy.AddMessage(" TP table " +layerpPath)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Expression .... " + expression)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layerpPath, ['Shape@'], expression) as cursor:

            for row in cursor:
                isFound = True
                arcpy.AddMessage("line TP FOUND IN THE TABLE... ")

                tp = row[0]
    if isFound == False:
         preResult = AutoPreprocess.preprocess(y,x)
         arcpy.AddMessage ("NOT FOUND IN TP - PREPROCESSED RAN")
         with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layerpPath, ['Shape@'], expression) as cursor:

            for row in cursor:
                isFound = True
                arcpy.AddMessage("FOUND AFTER PREPROCESSED... ")

                tp = row[0]


    return tp
```

**UPDATE:**
so I think I may be on track to a possible solution. There is an expensive operation that occurs during one table operation later in the script. I think this might be locking resources on the table/sde when the other threads try to access.

```
 
    hpsaSubTypeWhereClause = whereHPSACondition

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hpsaFC, "in_memory\\hpsaFC_layer") # Delete in_memory?

    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management ("in_memory\\hpsaFC_layer", "INTERSECT", "in_memory\\outTPLayer")
    

    arcpy.Select_analysis ("in_memory\\hpsaFC_layer", "in_memory\\NSCArea",hpsaSubTypeWhereClause)

    arcpy.Erase_analysis("in_memory\\outTPLayer", "in_memory\\NSCArea", "in_memory\\FinalNSCArea", "")

    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\outTPLayer")
```

the arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management of hpsaFC take a while and so does the select by location. The feature class this pulls from is large about 10200 rows of polygons. If I can make the above sequence of calls more efficient then it may prevent locks. Anyone have any ideas on how to query the FC faster or do an intersect operation faster without all the in_memory feature layer creation?

Comment: Non-answer, just my experiences of doing a LOT with GP Services years ago: mutlprocessing and GP Services didn't (still dont?) mix well. Little to no testing (ie, not officially supported, not officially not not supported), and very hard to debug.

Comment: Does your geoprocessing script use multi threading or does the app make multiple calls to the service? If it is the app then how many service instances are allowed? Maybe there are not enough soc.exe available. If it is the geoprocessing script can you try setting the workspace environment before threading instead of using the full path within the function?

Comment: the app makes multithreaded calls to the geoporcessing service. I've got a max of 20 instances on the service so there should be enough soc.exe. I think I tried setting the sde as the workspace as well but there was no difference.

Comment: I completely missed the mutlithreading direction in your question. Per @Dowlers line of thinking, does your database limit the number of connections?

Comment: @mayro double check the geoprocessing service is published as async? Maybe your sql server instance is under provisioned? Would it be an option to test using a FGDB instead?

Comment: Updated my post. To answer questions. No i have not see any limits on connections. The service is published as synchronous. There would have to be a lot of writing of application for it to be able to receive asynchronous responses from the geoprocessing service. Plus when I tested it as async the errors were still present. not sure if I understand how the sql server would be under provisioned? I have started to test switching to FGCB but haven't gone down that rabbit whole since it would require removing a lot of data from our DB then maintain in the gis server.